# Polymer Iron-Icon Size not Changing

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

I'm having some trouble adjusting the size of an `iron-icon` I'm using. I can see that the width and height I'm setting is being applied to `.iron-icon-1` (when I inspect in chrome dev tools) - but the visible size of the icon is not changing.

Put the relevant code below (for reference I've included it's containing div in case that's relevant).

```
<div class="user-avatar-overlay"><iron-icon icon="icons:check" class="overlay-tick"></iron-icon></div>

.user-avatar-overlay {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.overlay-tick {
    --iron-icon-fill-color: white; //This styling is being applied correctly
    --iron-icon-height: 25px;
    --iron-icon-width: 25px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use tag-name with class? `iron-icon.overlay-tick {}`

Comment: Yes, doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing if this is inside another Polymer Element or not... I put together this quick JSbin, I realize its using 2.0-preview branch but in this case, the CSS part doesnt change. I also included just about ever typical way you might style the icons... using the --iron-icon css vars, straight height/width css as well as a parent selector option.

https://jsbin.com/niqexomufa/edit?html,output

Note: if this doesn't help, providing more details on your actual usage (like a jsbin or something) will go along way in troubleshooting your exact problems.

(relevant CSS and DOM from the  are below to appease the SO gods)

```
        iron-icon.enormous {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
        }
        iron-icon.tiny {
          --iron-icon-height: 10px;
          --iron-icon-width: 10px;
        }
        .another {
          --iron-icon-height: 20px;
          --iron-icon-width: 20px;
        }

      <div>An enormous icon goes here: <iron-icon class="enormous" icon="icons:check"></iron-icon></div>
      <div>A tiny icon goes here: <iron-icon class="tiny" icon="icons:check"></iron-icon></div>        
      <div class="another">Another icon goes here: <iron-icon icon="icons:check"></iron-icon></div>
```